# Cant access internet when DNAT 80 port to raspberry nginx

Tags: linux, networking, raspberry-pi

I have following network configuration.

```
+---------------+                                                                      
|   Raspberry   +------+                                                               
| 192.168.1.130 |      |          +--------------------+          +-------------------+
+---------------+      +----------+                    |wan       |                   |
                              lan |       Router       +----------+    internet..     |
+---------------+      +----------+     192.168.1.1    |          |                   |
|     User      |      |          +--------------------+          +-------------------+
| 192.168.1.111 +------+                                                               
+---------------+
```

- Raspberry running nginx as proxy on port 3128.
- In router there is **DNAT : 80 -> 192.168.1.130:3128**
  wich means I want to forward all traffic to raspberry nginx.

Problem  - nginx does not log any access - and I can't get out to the internet on 80 port.

If I directly put nginx ip and port in browser proxy configuration it works, but i want define it in router.

Any ideas?

**Raspberry info:**

```
Linux raspberrypi 3.18.3+ #741 PREEMPT Fri Jan 23 13:32:52 GMT 2015 armv6l GNU/Linux
pi@raspberrypi$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
iptables - off
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your ISP, and make sure they do not block port 80. If they do, you'll have to access from the internet via a non-blocked port, and forward that port to your rasp pi.

Comment: nop, 80 port is not blocked, if I remove DNAT from router then everything is ok, but I need that all traffic go through raspberry.